# How to convert a tensorflow Graph into using the Estimator API

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm a little stuck on trying to convert my tensorflow code into using the Estimator API

My graph is below

```
batch_size = 1024

embedding_size = 500 # 2^8 Dimension of the embedding vector. Crashed at 158 for Embed size 2656016. So possible values are 154-157. Possible choices 154, 156
num_inputs =5

num_sampled = 128 # Number of negative examples to sample.

graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default(): 

    train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, num_inputs ])
    train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 1])

    epochCount = tf.get_variable( 'epochCount', initializer= 0) #to store epoch count to total # of epochs are known
    update_epoch = tf.assign(epochCount, epochCount + 1)

    embeddings = tf.get_variable( 'embeddings', dtype=tf.float32,
        initializer= tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0, dtype=tf.float32) )

    softmax_weights = tf.get_variable( 'softmax_weights', dtype=tf.float32,
        initializer= tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],
                             stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size), dtype=tf.float32 ) )

    softmax_biases = tf.get_variable('softmax_biases', dtype=tf.float32,
        initializer= tf.zeros([vocabulary_size], dtype=tf.float32),  trainable=False )

    embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset) #train data set is

    embed_reshaped = tf.reshape( embed, [batch_size*num_inputs, embedding_size] )

    segments= np.arange(batch_size).repeat(num_inputs)

    averaged_embeds = tf.segment_mean(embed_reshaped, segments, name=None)

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_weights, biases=softmax_biases, inputs=averaged_embeds, 
                                   sampled_values=tf.nn.uniform_candidate_sampler(true_classes=tf.cast(train_labels, tf.int64), num_sampled=num_sampled, num_true=1, unique=True, range_max=vocabulary_size, seed=None),
                                   labels=train_labels, num_sampled=num_sampled, num_classes=vocabulary_size)) 

    optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss) 

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

I'm reading the official Estimator guide here

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator

My best interpretation on what to do is that I have to convert my graph into a function? And set that to `model_fn`?

'params' are the my embeddings and softmax weights. So do I explicitly name these variables here?

Edit:

Thanks to answers from Sorin, this is my attempt at converting this to using TF.Estimator

This is the function I used to generate batches of data.

data_index = 0
epoch_index = 0
recEpoch_indexA = 0 #Used to help keep store of the total number of epoches with the models

```
def generate_batch(batch_size, inputCount): #batch size = number of labels
  #inputCount = number of inputs per label
    global data_index, epoch_index

    batch = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size, inputCount), dtype=np.int32) 
    labels = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size, 1), dtype=np.int32)

    #Begin New stuff

    n=0
    while n < batch_size:
      if len(    set(my_data[data_index, 1])   ) >= inputCount:
        labels[n,0] = my_data[data_index, 0]
        batch[n] = random.sample( set(my_data[data_index, 1]),  inputCount)
        n = n+1
        data_index = (data_index + 1) % len(my_data) #may have to do something like len my_data[:]
        if data_index == 0:
          epoch_index = epoch_index + 1
          print('Completed %d Epochs' % epoch_index)
      else:
        data_index = (data_index + 1) % len(my_data)
        if data_index == 0:
          epoch_index = epoch_index + 1
          print('Completed %d Epochs' % epoch_index)

    return batch, labels
```

This is where I define my model function. I commented out the place holders and put in the train data and train labels as the input

```
def my_model( train_dataset, train_labels):

#     train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, num_inputs ])
#     train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 1])

    epochCount = tf.get_variable( 'epochCount', initializer= 0) #to store epoch count to total # of epochs are known
    update_epoch = tf.assign(epochCount, epochCount + 1)

    embeddings = tf.get_variable( 'embeddings', dtype=tf.float32,
        initializer= tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0, dtype=tf.float32) )

    softmax_weights = tf.get_variable( 'softmax_weights', dtype=tf.float32,
        initializer= tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],
                             stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size), dtype=tf.float32 ) )

    softmax_biases = tf.get_variable('softmax_biases', dtype=tf.float32,
        initializer= tf.zeros([vocabulary_size], dtype=tf.float32),  trainable=False )

    embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset) #train data set is

    embed_reshaped = tf.reshape( embed, [batch_size*num_inputs, embedding_size] )

    segments= np.arange(batch_size).repeat(num_inputs)

    averaged_embeds = tf.segment_mean(embed_reshaped, segments, name=None)

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_weights, biases=softmax_biases, inputs=averaged_embeds, 
                                   sampled_values=tf.nn.uniform_candidate_sampler(true_classes=tf.cast(train_labels, tf.int64), num_sampled=num_sampled, num_true=1, unique=True, range_max=vocabulary_size, seed=None),
                                   labels=train_labels, num_sampled=num_sampled, num_classes=vocabulary_size)) 

    optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss) 

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

This is where I define the Estimator

```
#Define the estimator
word2vecEstimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(
        model_fn=my_model,
        params={
            'batch_size': 1024,
            'embedding_size': 50,
            'num_inputs': 5,
            'num_sampled':128
        })
```

This is where I tell the Estimator to train

```
#Train with Estimator
word2vecEstimator.train(
    input_fn=lambda:iris_data.generate_batch(batch_size, num_inputs),
    steps=1000)
```

Does this seem right?

Also, after a certain amount of steps, I would like to save the checkpoint and upload it to my google drive. I was wondering how/where I would place the code to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, model_fn is the way to go.

Params is more about hyperparameters than anything else. Any variable you have you should keep in the model(as it is).

You shouldn't have any placeholders in your new function. They come via the features and labels.

One thing to watch for is that the same function is callled for predictions, training and evaluation. Use the mode parameter to distinguish. This also means label is None when you do predictions, so make sure the code works correctly in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried to implement it, I edited the answer above with my attempt. Also, after a certain amount of steps, I would like to save the checkpoint and upload it to my google drive. I was wondering how/where I would place the code to do that.

Comment: @SantoshGupta7 that's the easy part. After you do `word2vecEstimator.train(...)` you call `word2vecEstimator.export_saved_model(...)`. You'll need to provide another input function to match how you plan to use the model (not parse labels, no shuffle, things like that).